# Keyboard layout appears twice in upper panel

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with mate desktop, and trying to add a new keyboard layout.

This is how I do it:
System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard

Then I added another language:
[image]

In the upper panel I see the layout twice>
[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following:

1. Visit Language Support (`gnome-language-selector`) application to set *Keyboard input method system* to *None*

   [image: Keyboard input method system → None]
2. Do right mouse click on blue EN (IBus Preferences interface) on the top MATE Panel, then uncheck *Show icon on system tray*

   [image: Show icon on system tray is unchecked]

   and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks!! Although I liked more the blue one.... :-)